# VBA Error with Taking the Average of a Set of Scores

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to take the scores of a test from cells 2 to 19 and set that equal to 20. However, when I enter the code it only prints out `#NAME?`. How can I fix it to make sure it prints the average score?

```
Sub Scores()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    ws.Activate
    Dim rngStart As Range
    Dim rngEnd As Range
    Set rngStart = Range("A1").Cells(2, 5)
    Set rngEnd = Range("A1").Cells(19, 5)
    Dim MidtermAvg As Range
    Set MidtermAvg = Range(rngEnd.Offset(1, 0), rngEnd.Offset(1, 0))
    ' Put in average at the bottom of the range
    MidtermAvg.Formula = "=AVERAGE(rngEnd:rngStart)"
End Sub
```

Here are the scores all lined in one column:

```
63
44
87
96
67
82
58
71
61
77
63
30
93
38
89
89
93
93
```

Answer (score 3):

You were missing some of the worksheet references,
and your formula had the `rngStart` and `rngEnd` variables hiding in a string.
(How would VBA know that those are variables?)

Also, you need to get the `.Address` of those range objects.
This works:

```
Sub Scores()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    ws.Activate
    Dim rngStart As Range
    Dim rngEnd As Range
    Set rngStart = ws.Range("A1").Cells(2, 5)
    Set rngEnd = ws.Range("A1").Cells(19, 5)
    Dim MidtermAvg As Range
    Set MidtermAvg = ws.Range(rngEnd.Offset(1, 0), rngEnd.Offset(1, 0))
    ' Put in average at the bottom of the range
    MidtermAvg.Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & rngStart.Address & ":" & rngEnd.Address & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 :) A small change? "Set MidtermAvg = ws.Range(rngEnd.Offset(1, 0), rngEnd.Offset(1, 0))"
The first one should be "rngStart"

Comment: Thank you, Siddharth. Actually, the goal of that line was to get the average into the cell below the range of numbers, so the `rngEnd` is used twice. It ends up being something like `E20:E20`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using `Range("A1")` and then `Cells(r,c)` notation  to get the range `"E2:E19"`. If the scores are in that range then why not as follows:

```
Sub AverageScore()
    Dim scores As Range
    Set scores = Range("E2:E" & Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row)
    Range("E" & scores.End(xlDown).Row).Offset(1, 0) = "Avg: " & Round(WorksheetFunction.Average(scores), 2)
End Sub
```

NB - I have taken the liberty of rounding the average to 2 decimal points and adding a labelso that the result reads `Avg: 71.89` but you can change as you see fit.